# sharepoint integration with java web services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

we want to integrate sharepoint to our existing portal. The purpose of doing this is to use some of the features of sharepoint such as wiki,blogs etc. 
is there any way we can aechvie this i.e. intigrating to our existing portal to use only specific services of share point.